# Call to virtual function in base class crash

Tags: c++, boost, recursion, polymorphism

I have an issue with some call to a protected virtual function in a public recursive one.

What I want to have is a **Base** class that calls a recursive function ***getAllStrings()***, this one then calls a ***virtual getString()*** function on all items of its "children" list.
The ***getString()*** method is only implemented in some of its children classes.

// Base.hpp

```
class Base
{
private:
    // SharedBase is a typedef boost::shared_ptr<Base>
    std::list<SharedBase> baseList;

protected:
    virtual std::string getString() const
    {
        return "";
    };

public:
    Base(){}
    virtual ~Base(){}

    void addElmtToList(SharedBase sb)
    {
        baseList.push_back(sb);
    }

    // recursive
    void getAllStrings(std::string &returnedString)
    {
        if (!baseList.empty())
        {
            // Iterate through all children
            std::list<SharedBase>::iterator itBase = baseList.begin();
            while (itBase != baseList.end())
            {
                (*itBase)->getAllStrings(returnedString);
                ++itBase;
            }
        }

        returnedString += getString(); // ERROR !
    }

};
```

// Derived_a.hpp

```
class Derived_a : public Base
{
public:
    Derived_a();
    virtual ~Derived_a();

protected:
    std::string getString() const
    {
        return "derived_a string";
    }
};
```

// Derived_b.hpp

```
class Derived_b : public Base
{
public:
    Derived_b();
    virtual ~Derived_b();
};
```

So basicaly the application call for ***getAllStrings()*** and everything works fine except the call to ***getString()***, which makes the application crash.

Simply calling the ***getString()*** function without any recursivity (comment the *if* block) makes the application crash anyway.

Putting it non-virtual makes it work but the function is useless in this case so I'm kind of lost. Why does it crash ?

**EDIT 10/03:** Added SSCCE [here](http://codepad.org/zlDvwFsT). Based upon Synxis code. Works on my computer with Boost linked. So I guess it really has something to do with our application's environment.

Comment: How does it crash? What did debugging tell you? And can you show how you're calling it in the first place? Ideally, provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Unrelated, but your `if (!baseList.empty())` line is completely redundant.

Comment: @Angew: debugging does not work in the project due to the use of some .dll. The only error I'm getting is an "invalid handle".

Comment: Take your above code and make a small concise example that replicates the problem, then try to debug that.

Comment: I don't understand. Sure, maybe you can't step/debug into a 3rd party DLL, but your code is still debuggable, right?

Comment: Can you post how you call the `getString()` function (including the object creation) ?

Comment: @Angew The dll are in release state, so I can't compile in debug (would be useful tho). I may provide a SSCCE but I'm quite busy atm, what the main application does is basically call the getAllString() function from a SharedBase.

Comment: @eMixam You can still disable optimisations and enable debug info (for your code) while using the non-debug runtime.

Comment: [Works here](http://codepad.org/3HlAAU4H). I suspect that there is some logic in `getAllStrings` that is not shown... (including that everything before getString can be rewritten in 2 lines) Usually, I encounter these types of bugs when the recursion is spanning multiple objects and the recursion is called on an invalid object pointer

Comment: ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Synxis `getAllStrings` as presented here is the same as the one I'm using in the application. I would say that it's an invalid object pointer too if it worked when I'm commenting the whole recursivity part, but it doesn't...

Comment: Could you complete the example with the code calling getAllString(s) that produces the crash? Ideally a small main function which reproduces the crash on your system.

Comment: @Jens The function is called after a Qt button clicked() signal is emitted. Also, added a SSCCE in main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue.

I made a trace with DrMinGW showing that a signal was called before segfaulting in `ntdll.dll!RtlUlonglongByteSwap`

However, no signals were used in the function.

Here is the culprit:

// In the "base.hpp" file

```
protected:

    /// Some useful type definition for the signal to emit when the
    /// configuration changes.
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void ()> OnConfigurationUpdated;

    virtual std::string getString()
    {
       return "";
    }

public:
    /// Signal that subscribers have to connect to if they want to be alerted
    /// about the configuration changes.
    OnConfigurationUpdated reactOnChanges;
```

The project uses another project Serialization from where the classes are imported. However, this project wasn't rebuilt with the GUI. Cleaning properly (removing .o and .dll files) from the Serialization project got it working.